# How should I create a temporary table when Union is used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, group-by

I can't use Dynamic Value bcoz of Error stating
"Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Here is the Scenario :
Query 1

```
select pr.PRDCT,sum(CASE when pr.DEFINITIONCD='NOP' and pr.PERIOD='D' then pr.PRAMOUNT else 0 END)
as 'NOP D' from PRODUCTWISE_REPORT pr group by pr.PRDCT
```

Query 2

```
select DEFINITIONTYPECD from REPORTKPIMAPTXN where DEFINITIONTYPECD='NOP' and REPORTSEQ = (select REPORTSEQ from report_m where REPORTCD='MIS_Product_Wise_Report')
```

Query 2 returns 'NOP'

so when I put Query 2 in Query 1 for 'NOP', it throws Error

How to resolve this when I've to User Dynamic Query 2 ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query looks it could be rewritten with a join instead of that subselect. something like this. Of course you are still going to have some issues because your first query has two columns and this has only 1 column. You will have to add another column (can be NULL) to this query before the UNION will actually work.

```
select r.DEFINITIONTYPECD 
from REPORTKPIMAPTXN r
INNER JOIN report_m m on m.REPORTSEQ = r.REPORTSEQ
where DEFINITIONTYPECD = 'NOP' 
and r.REPORTCD = 'MIS_Product_Wise_Report'
```